# prettyPhoto Not Working - Error: Not a Function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm having some issues with prettyPhoto on one of my clients website. Here is the link for reference: http://www.browardmicrofilm.com/pages/kodak-vizit-essential.html

I've used prettyPhoto on multiple other websites without issue. However for some reason, this website just doesn't want to perform the script properly. Instead of opening an image in the lightbox clone, it simply opens it in a new page. Perhaps it has something to do with the hosting but either way, wanted to see what professionals like you think!

I'm using Firefox 26 (Mac version) and I used Firebug to determine the error:

```
TypeError: $ is not a function
$(document).ready(function(){
```

I've tried numerous solutions, including one that made me change "$" to "window.jQuery and then for some reason the next line in the code creates the same error.

Here's the my code for those of you that wish to skip the entire page source code:

In my header:

```
<link href="../prettyPhoto.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/jquery.prettyPhoto.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
```

The final script just before the closing body tag:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto({
    theme: 'light_rounded',
});
});
</script>
```

I know my links are good, which is why I'm not including them.

Comment: I think jquery needs to be added before any sub-library in the header.

Answer (score 6):

Vanilla jquery needs to be declared before any library built on top of it

```
<!--first, jquery-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
<!--then the rest-->
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/jquery.prettyPhoto.js"></script>
```

Comment: Well, I've moved the jquery01.6.1.min.js file above everything else, just to be sure. Still getting the same error.

Comment: Can you try <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script> ?

Comment: I've added that but it sprouted a 404 Page not found. I've since removed it.

Comment: So weird, it works just fine on my side. Did you solve your problem? If you put your page up (even if it doesn't work) and send me the URL I can try to help

Answer (score 1):

Error below is saying that jQuery is not loaded.

```
TypeError: $ is not a function
$(document).ready(function(){
```

Check your resources, my guess is that your paths are case sensitive and libraries are not being properly loaded.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/jquery.prettyPhoto.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
```

Check your resources.

Comment: I've check my resources. In fact I've dragged n' dropped the files into the code within dreamweaver, which populates the field as it should be. Still getting issue.

Comment: @user3179689 It's been some time since I've used DW and I'm not familiar how the resources are allocated. On your uploaded page, right click -> view source and click on the two .js libraries to make sure they are loaded on the server.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that jQuery is loaded before the plugin is loaded.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/jquery.prettyPhoto.js"></script>
```

Comment: Well, I've moved the jquery01.6.1.min.js file above everything else, just to be sure. Still getting the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately I abandoned the prettyPhoto javascript and went with an alternative. Lightbox 2.0:

http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox2/

It works just as I'd like and no problems.

Comment: I don't know why the down vote. I'm with same issue. All other scripts run fine, jquery is called first but no way this prettyphoto script to work.

Comment: This plugin uses last version on jQuery and doesn't cause problem with other plugins that using jQuery ...